# c# Calculo de diferença datas com separador ponto

Tags: c#

Estou a tentar calcular a diferença entre 2 datas e horas, o formato em que aparecem no ficheiro é:

dia-mês-ano hora

Exemplo

> hora inicial

```
17.11.17 22:55:12:968
```

> hora final

```
18.11.17 00:31:35:974
```

já tentei várias coisas como:

```
DateTime dataUm = DateTime.Parse("17.11.17 19:06:35:625"); 
DateTime dataDois = DateTime.Parse("17.11.17 21:56:52:232");

TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dataDois.Ticks-dataUm.Ticks);
```

Mas obtenho sempre erros:

> ---
>
> ### Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Exceção encontrada. Isso pode ser causado por uma extensão.

Comment: Eu ia fechar como não clara, mas acho que isto resolve, porque o problema é só a cultura ou a máscara.

Comment: Mude os valores de entrada no arquivo para `"17.11.17 22:55:12:968"` e `"18.11.17 00:31:35:974"`. Eu acredito que os milissegundos deveriam estar separados por `"."` ao invés de `":"`. Se a entrada nesse formato for um requisito, você terá que fazer o `parse` para DateTime especificando exatamente o formato de entrada

Comment: Boa noite estes dados são de uma máquina, tenho de os tratar do modo que chegam.